# flutter plugins on m1 Mac shows error "Module 'foo' not found"

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

I'm moving my Flutter projects to my new **M1** MacBook Pro.
I get the following error for all my plugins / dependencies (listed in pubspec.yaml) when trying to build:
**"Module 'foo' not found"**

On the [official Flutter install page (for M1)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon) they say to run this command:

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

Did that, but with no luck...
Also followed [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907), no luck either...

I'm familiar with developing Flutter apps on Mac, but all this is kind of voodoo for me, and I'm not sure I'm doing this right.
If someone was able to run a Flutter project with plugins on the M1, I'd love to hear how

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by:

1. creating a new Flutter project
2. copy all the dart + yaml + assets files from the old project to the newly created one

Still had to run the following commend (still have no clue what it does):

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
```

Hope it helps other who encountered this

P.S.
Trying to upgrade the old Flutter project failed (didn't help)

Comment: didn't work for me on m1 Mac